# Accessing props values inside of local component vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I have a `Vue` Instance with two local components, both the components are having `props` from the data of the Vue Instance. But when I try to access the `props` values from one of the local component the values ae undefined.

This is the code

```
var custom_erp_widget = new Vue({
    el : '#custom-erp-widgets',
    data : {
        showContainerHeader : false,
        currentModuleName : 'foo',
        currentModuleFormID : '5',
        currentModuleReportID : '6'
    },
    components : {
        'custom-erp-header' : {
            template : '<div class="col-12" id="custom-erp-widget-header">'+
                        '{{ currentModuleName.toUpperCase() }}'+
                       '</div>',
            props : ['currentModuleName']
        },
        'custom-erp-body' : {
            template : '<div class="col-12" id="custom-erp-widget-body">'+
                       '</div>',
            props : ['currentModuleFormID','currentModuleReportID'],
            // for emitting events so that the child components
            // like (header/body) can catch and act accordingly
            created() {
                var _this = this;
                eventHub.$on('getFormData', function(e) {
                    if(e == 'report'){
                        console.log(_this.$props);

                        _this.getReportData();
                    }
                    else if(e == 'form'){
                        console.log(_this.$props);
                        _this.getFormData();
                    }

                });

              },

            methods : {
                // function to get the form data from the server
                // for the requested form
                getFormData : function(){
                    var _this = this;
                    //here the logs are returinig undefined
                    //but it is having values in the data from the root Instance
                    console.log(_this.$props.currentModuleFormID);
                    console.log(_this.currentModuleFormID);

                    axios
                        .get('http://localhost:3000/getFormData',{
                            params: {
                                formID: _this.currentModuleFormID + 'a'
                            }
                        })
                        .then(function(response){

                            console.log(response);

                        })
                }

            }

        }
    },

})
```

This is the HTML usage of the component

```
<div class="row" id="custom-erp-widgets" v-show="showContainerHeader">

    <custom-erp-header :current-module-name='currentModuleName'></custom-erp-header>    
    <custom-erp-body></custom-erp-body>

</div>
```

How can I access the props values in the local component function?

[image: Ouptput]

Comment: Try this.props?

Comment: I able to access the props, the problem is that there value is undefined. formID inside the axios is undefined.

Comment: Can you show html template code where you use `custom-erp-body`?

Comment: Please check now, I have updated the HTML in the question @ittus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the problem is your [prop names](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#Prop-Casing-camelCase-vs-kebab-case) because Vue expects a kebab-cased form of your prop names in DOM templates.

> HTML attribute names are case-insensitive, so browsers will interpret
> any uppercase characters as lowercase. That means when you’re using
> in-DOM templates, camelCased prop names need to use their kebab-cased
> (hyphen-delimited) equivalents.

So for `currentModuleFormID` it expects `current-module-form-i-d` in the DOM template, not `current-module-form-id` as you would expect. Try changing `currentModuleFormID` to `currentModuleFormId` with a lower case `d` at the end and use `current-module-form-id` in the template and I'm guessing it should work.

```
var custom_erp_widget = new Vue({
    el : '#custom-erp-widgets',
    data : {
        showContainerHeader : false,
        currentModuleName : 'foo',
        currentModuleFormId : '5',
        currentModuleReportId : '6'
    },
  ....
```

---

```
<custom-erp-body 
  :current-module-form-id="currentModuleFormId" 
  :current-module-report-id ="currentModuleReportId">
</custom-erp-body>
```

Comment: Thanks great catch @Husam, thank you for the help. But for whatver reason I am not able to access the values inside the `axios` params. Do you know the reason for that?

Comment: @Rehan Glad to help. Can you please elaborate Re: axios? It would be better if you could update your question.

Comment: I will open a new question and reference it here.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53003261/props-value-are-not-enpty-inside-axios  @Husam

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass props to `custom-erp-body` component:

```
<custom-erp-body 
  :currentModuleFormID="currentModuleFormID" 
  :currentModuleReportID ="currentModuleReportID">
</custom-erp-body>
```

Comment: I have tried that as well, but still it says undefined.