# Props value are not updating inside axios

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a `Vue` instance with two local `components`, when I try to get some data from server using `axios` the `props` because empty when try to pass it in the `GET` params

```
var custom_erp_widget = new Vue({
    el : '#custom-erp-widgets',
    data : {
        showContainerHeader : false,
        currentModuleName : 'foo',
        currentModuleFormID : '5',
        currentModuleReportID : '6'
    },
    components : {
        'custom-erp-header' : {
            template : '<div class="col-12" id="custom-erp-widget-header">'+
                        '{{ currentModuleName.toUpperCase() }}'+
                       '</div>',
            props : ['currentModuleName']
        },
        'custom-erp-body' : {
            template : '<div class="col-12" id="custom-erp-widget-body">'+
                       '</div>',
            props : ['currentModuleFormId','currentModuleReportId'],
            // for emitting events so that the child components
            // like (header/body) can catch and act accordingly
            created() {
                var _this = this;
                eventHub.$on('getFormData', function(e) {
                    if(e == 'report'){
                        console.log(_this.$props);

                        _this.getReportData();
                    }
                    else if(e == 'form'){
                        console.log(_this.$props);
                        _this.getFormData();
                    }

                });

              },

            methods : {
                // function to get the form data from the server
                // for the requested form
                getFormData : function(){
                    var _this = this;
                    var x = _this.$props;
                    // here the props are having values
                    //currentModuleFormId: 1
                    //currentModuleReportId: 0
                    console.log(x);

                    axios
                        .get('http://localhost:3000/getFormData',{
                            params: {
                                //here both are '' in the server-side
                                formID: JSON.stringify(_this.$props) + 'a'
                            }
                        })
                        .then(function(response){

                            console.log(response);

                        })
                }

            }

        }
    },

})
```

This is the actual block

```
getFormData : function(){

    var _this = this;
    var x = _this.$props.currentModuleFormId;
    console.log(x);
    let urs = 'http://localhost:3000/getFormData?formID='+_this.$props.currentModuleFormId.toString();
    axios
        .get(urs , {
            params: {
              formID: _this.$props.currentModuleFormId
            }
        })
        .then(function(response){

            console.log(response);

        })
}
```

Output In network tab

[image]

Comment: What's the expected value in the formID field?

Comment: The props values which is `{currentModuleFormId: 1,currentModuleReportId: 0}`

Comment: Try to console.log `JSON.stringify(_this.$props) + 'a'` before the axios call and see if you get the value you expect.

Comment: Yes that is working correctly but when I do _this.$props.currentModuleFormId this thing is empty. How to access props values? Is there someother way to do that?\

Comment: In your comment you say it has a value of 1. Anyway you can either access it by `_this.$props.currentModuleFormId` or  `_this.$props['currentModuleFormId']`.

Comment: I have added the screenshot and the block, please check @HusamIbrahim
Even when I try to access in that way, it is still '' in the server side.

Comment: What do you get from that `console.log(x)`.  Did you also try setting your `formId` to `x`?

Comment: I just now found out that, only for the first time the props are having old values, from the second time the props behave as expected. I change the `data` in the root element and then call the `axios`, so that props values should also be updated,right?

Comment: Also please consider posting all relevant code, including templates so I can try and reproduce this. Bonus points if you take the time to create a jsfidfle/codepen/codesandbox so we can play live with your code and see what's wrong.

Comment: Yes that's correct. If things are set up correctly if you change the data in the parent component the props should update.